# Native crash at signal 5 / signal 11 - Chrome.apk

Tags: android

I have an increase of crashes in my Android app, all referring to Chrome.apk

Here is a list of the errors and the phone models:

```
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 4 (TRAP_HWBKPT)
    BQru BQ-5009L
    LGE LG K10 (2017)

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
    Oppo CPH1801
    Oppo CPH1725

signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 4 (TRAP_HWBKPT)
    Huawei 荣耀畅享7 Plus

signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT)
    Meizu meizu M6
```

I don't have any of these phones, so it's difficult to debug as I can't reproduce this on my test devices.

The app has some links to websites and the privacy policy, so this is where I guess it could crash. On the other hand, I have ads (banner and interstitial with AdMob), so it could be there too.

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: It happens on Android 7.x only

EDIT 2: It seems related to AdMob. Removing the ads results in no more reported crashes.

Comment: Did you find any solution, i am still facing this crash in 2022

Comment: @Diljeet no, I stopped investigating it, and currently I don't show ads if it's an Android 7 device.